# Efficiently Removing duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 28 million records but now it has 56 million records because I assumed the `load local infile` command would ignore rows that were already in the table. No I need a way to efficiently remove the duplicate rows. What is the best way to approach this?

If I do not want to touch my table can I just select unique rows by this statement:

```
select distinct (l1.lat, l2.lon) from A, B;
```

Comment: Empty the table and load the data again?

Comment: Duplicate rows also have same unique key or not?

Comment: If I empty the table then my ib1 file will grow exponentially and I do not have the rights to delete it. Duplicate keys have the same unique key.

Comment: As you are removing 50% of the records, starting again will almost always be fastest.  Reading all of the table, joining it to itself (involving a large sort if there isn't a useful index), then deleting half the records from the disk, well it will be intensive.

Comment: Not so unique anymore is it lol. Do you know exactly where the files end and where they start again? Meaning, do you have the unique key of the very last unique row before they start being duplicates? If so. Just do a delete where unique key > last unique row value

Comment: As a matter of preventative maintenance, after you fix the problem, you might want to set up an index to prevent duplicates from being added to any of your tables. Unless dupes are okay.

Comment: Something is missing. What are the other fields in that table?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is usually slower/inferior to `GROUP BY` - or so a good DBA friend drilled into my mellon.  Thanks for that, Matt.

Comment: If you can define a unique PK for the records, then you can create a new table with the defined PK and load the data using `insert ignore`, then delete the original table and rename the new one

Answer (score 5):

Select originals into a new/temp table, delete the 56 million records, insert your originals.

Example:
    INSERT INTO new_fresh_table
      SELECT a, b, c, d FROM table_with_dupes
      GROUP BY a, b, c, d

If you've lost duped your IDs somehow (not sure how that's possible with a PK), you need to use `GROUP BY` on every single column.  Write a `SELECT` against meta-data to write your `SELECT` for you.

Comment: "not sure how that's possible with a PK" - I agree, and the followup: if someone can figure out a way to do something *that makes absolutely no sense to do*, they will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how the records are duped. Is it Primary Key? Name? What?

From O'Reily's [SQL Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009762.do) (highly recommended, even for SQL pros):

```
delete from dupes
  where id not in ( select min(id) from dupes group by name )
```

Comment: Everything id duped. I have identical rows;

Comment: Does your table have a primary key? Use that instead of `id`. If no, then johnnyGold's answer is the best, and when you recreate your table, make sure you set a primary key and force it to be unique.

Comment: adding onto what bryanH said, if you put a numerical autoincrement column at the beginning then you won't have that problem as it forces any data changes to have a new value for that column and will never duplicate. Even if everything else is duplicated that will always remain unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot touch the table, and have to use it, why don't you create a view which only show you distinct records?

Comment: create view MyView as select distinct col1, col2, col3,... from MyTable; Then do this: select * from MyView;